# Evaluation the sine integral at infinity

Tags: integration

In an application of a limit theorem for stable laws, I came across this result
$$\int_{0}^\infty \left(1-\cos\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\right)\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

After trying a few substitution I asked Wolfram Alpha to compute this. It turns out that there is no function that expresses this integral, except the sine-integral $Si(t):=\int_0^t\sin(x)/x\,dx$.

Using a trigonometric identity and the substitution $x=1/(2y)$, we get for the indeterminate integral
$$\int_0^\infty\left(1-\cos\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\right)\,dx=-\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2(y)}{y^2}\,dy$$

Integration by parts with $u'=1/y^2$ and $v=\sin^2(y)$ gives (using L'Hopital)
$$-\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2(y)}{y^2}\,dy=-0+2\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(y)\cos(y)}{y}\,dy=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(2y)}{y}\,dy
\\=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(y)}{y}\,dy=\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow\infty}Si(\varepsilon).$$

How do I show that the last expression is equal to $\pi/2$ at infinity?

Comment: $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(y)}{y}\,dy=\frac {\pi} 2$ is a very basic result which can be found in many Calculus books. Many proofs of this are available on MSE.

Comment: Ah, i see. Feel free to delete or close this thread then. I couldn't find anything useful, but i might not have searched deeply enough.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin y}{y} dy.$$
Use $\frac{1}{y}=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-yt}dt$, then
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ty} \sin y dy$$$$=\Im\int_{0}^{\infty} dt\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-y(t-i)} dy.$$$$=\Im \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{t-i}$$$$=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{1+t^2}dt=\pi/2. $$

Comment: That's a nice trick.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{f(x)}{x}\;dx=\int_0^\infty\mathcal L (f(x))\;ds$$

$$=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{s^2+1}\;ds$$

$$=\arctan(\infty)-\arctan(0)$$

$$=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Can you specify what $\mathcal L(f(x))$ is?

Comment: The Laplace transform of sine

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

We aim to solve the following integral:

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}\;dx$$

For $\alpha=0$, our integral takes the following form:

$$I(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\exp(-\alpha x)\sin x}{x}\;dx$$

Differentiating both sides:

$$I'(\alpha)=\frac{d}{d\alpha}\int_0^\infty\frac{\exp(-\alpha x)\sin x}{x}\;dx$$

Employing Leibniz' Rule:

$$I'(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\left[\frac{\exp(-\alpha x)\sin x}{x}\right]\;dx$$

$$I'(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty\frac{-x\exp(-\alpha x)\sin x}{x}\;dx$$

$$I'(\alpha)=\int_\infty^0\exp(-\alpha x)\sin x\;dx$$

Using integration by parts twice, we have the following:

$$\int_\infty^0\exp(-\alpha x)\sin x\;dx=-\exp(-\alpha x)\cos x\Big|_\infty^0-\alpha\exp(-\alpha x)\sin x\Big|_\infty^0-\alpha^2\int_\infty^0\exp(-\alpha x)\sin x\;dx$$

$$\implies (1+\alpha^2)\int_{\infty}^0\exp(-\alpha x)\sin x\;dx=-1$$

$$\implies \int_{\infty}^0\exp(-\alpha x)\sin x\;dx=\frac{-1}{1+\alpha^2}$$

$$\therefore I'(\alpha)=\frac{-1}{1+\alpha^2}$$

$$\implies I(\alpha)=-\arctan(\alpha)+C$$

Note the following:

$$\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}I(\alpha)=\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}\int_0^\infty\frac{\exp(-\alpha x)\sin x}{x}\;dx=0$$

$$\implies\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}-\arctan(\alpha)+C=0$$

$$\implies C=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

$$\implies I(\alpha)=-\arctan(\alpha)+\frac{\pi}{2}$$

$$\implies \int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}\;dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{Si}(t)\sim\frac \pi 2+\left(\frac{2}{t^3}-\frac{1}{t}\right) \cos (t)-\frac{\sin(t)}{t^2}$$ which is extremely accurate.

For $t=100$, the baove gives $1.562225500$ while the exact value is                            $1.562225467$

Comment: Isn't the exaxt value about 1.5707963 ?